# Derivation of OLS estimator

Tags: least-squares, estimators

Dear mathematicians/statisticians,

I have a question regarding the derivation of the OLS estimators. In one explanation I have found the following step:

[image]

However, I don't understand why it's -b_1 instead of +b_1 in the second equation? Shouldn't the term be positive because we removed the brackets?

x = a - (b - c) becomes x = a - b + c, right?

The source of the image of the explanation is: http://isites.harvard.edu/fs/docs/icb.topic515975.files/OLSDerivation.pdf

Comment: I think you are right. It is probably a typo

Comment: This is a typo. Look at the equation 11 in the document. The sign is correct there, although it does not follow from the equation before it.